# Issues with nodes returned by querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing an outside click hooks by class name

```
const useClickOutside = (className, f) => {

    function handleClickOutside(event) {

        if(event.which !== 1) return
        const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(className)
        console.log(nodes.length) // display the right length
        console.log(nodes) // display the right elements
        nodes.some((node) => { // falls
            let outside = !node.contains(event.target)
            if(outside) { f(); }
            return outside
        })

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
        return () =>  document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    }, []);

}
```

i call the hooks like that

```
useClickOutside(".foo", 
    () => {
        // some code ...
    }, 
);
```

i got this error `TypeError: nodes.some is not a function` even if just before the some function i got everything working on the nodes array !!

**SOLUTION**
thanks to @enapupe answer we can use also `ES6`

```
const nodes = [ ...document.querySelectorAll(className) ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

The NodeList type is not compatible with an array type, which has `some`.

You can do `Array.from(selector)` in order to use regular array prototypes on top of it.

```
const useClickOutside = (className, f) => {
  function handleClickOutside(event) {
    if (event.which !== 1) return
    const nodes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(className))
    nodes.some((node) => {
      let outside = !node.contains(event.target)
      if (outside) {
        f()
      }
      return outside
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
    return () => document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
  }, [])
}
```